# How to parse .XML data for unsecured networks

Tags: xml, powershell

I need some help with parsing a file that contains local networks and removes them from the .XML if its labeled as an openNetwork. All this in power shell. Here is an example of a snippet from a users file. I would like the PS to remove the SSID name if it is labeled as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserConfiguration major_version="5" minor_version="2" development_version="1">
    <networks>
        <group>
            <groupName>Local networks</groupName>
            <allowUserToSeeScanlist>true</allowUserToSeeScanlist>
            <allowUserToCreateNetworks>true</allowUserToCreateNetworks>
            <wifiNetwork>
                <displayName>xxx</displayName>
                <connectionTimeout>40</connectionTimeout>
                <ssid>
                    <name>xxx</name>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                </ssid>
                <associationTimeout>5</associationTimeout>
                <corporate>false</corporate>
                <sharedKeyNetwork>
                    <userConnection>
                        <wpa2>
                            <keyFromProfile>
                                <ascii persistentHandle="true">
                                    <EncryptedData
                                        xmlns="xxx">
                                        <CipherData>
                                            <CipherValue>xxx</CipherValue>
                                        </CipherData>
                                    </EncryptedData>
                                </ascii>
                            </keyFromProfile>
                            <encryption>AES</encryption>
                        </wpa2>
                    </userConnection>
                </sharedKeyNetwork>
            </wifiNetwork>
            <wifiNetwork>
                <displayName>xxx</displayName>
                <connectionTimeout>40</connectionTimeout>
                <ssid>
                    <name>xxx</name>
                    <hidden>false</hidden>
                </ssid>
                <associationTimeout>5</associationTimeout>
                <corporate>false</corporate>
                <openNetwork>
                    <userConnection/>
                </openNetwork>
            </wifiNetwork>
        </group>
    </networks>
</UserConfiguration>
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57332379/edit) your question ad insert a complete loadable xml. As it is now, the question is too vague to properly answer.

Comment: added full snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not totally clear what you want to remove from the xml exactly.. The entire `wifiNetwork` node or just the name inside the `<ssid>` tag.

Assuming you would like to remove the entire `wifiNetwork` node if it has an `openNetwork` element:

```
# load the xml file from disk
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'D:\UserConfiguration.xml' -Raw

# filter out all wifiNetwork nodes that have an openNetwork element and remove these nodes
$xml.DocumentElement.networks.group.wifiNetwork | Where-Object {$_.openNetwork} | ForEach-Object {
    [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
}

# save the xml to a new file
$xml.Save('D:\NewUserConfiguration.xml')
```

If however, you want just the `ssid` name cleared from the xml, use this:

```
# load the xml file from disk
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'D:\UserConfiguration.xml' -Raw

# filter out all wifiNetwork nodes that have an openNetwork element and remove the ssid name from them
$xml.DocumentElement.networks.group.wifiNetwork | Where-Object {$_.openNetwork} | ForEach-Object {
    # this will leave the element formatted like this:  <name></name>
    $_.ssid.name = [string]::Empty
    # collapse the now empty element to look like this: <name />
    $_.ssid.GetElementsByTagName('name')[0].IsEmpty = $true
}

# save the xml to a new file
$xml.Save('D:\NewUserConfiguration.xml')
```

For safety reasons I save the updated XML with a new filename in order to not overwrite the original.

Hope that helps

Comment: this works so far - my goal is to remove the entire <wifiNetwork> group if openNetwork is present

Comment: @Shane Well, in that case, use the first part of my answer. This will remove the entire `<wifiNetwork>` node from the xml

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple moving parts to this request, I would suggest at least trying to write some of the script yourself, and then asking questions here if you run into problems. No script runs perfectly the first time, but if you take a look at what you're testing for, you should have an easy time.

I also note that you haven't given us the complete xml file. There are a bunch of terminating tags in your paste that might have been useful to see the whole scope of when solving this problem.

I would start by reading in your xml file. You can read in XML files as an XML object like this:

`[xml]$xmlData = Get-Content C:\foo.xml`

There's a terminating tag for something called `networks`, you can collect all of the network objects in the xml by calling that attribute from the xml object.

`$xmlData.network`

Here, I'm going to assume that each of these "`<network>`s" is inside a `<group>` tag. That makes processing each node a little easier. You can say:

```
Foreach ($networkGroup in $xmlData.network.group) {
   if ( $networkGroup.openNetwork -ne $true) {
      $result += $networkGroup
   }
}
```

Now your `$result` contains the xml data without any of the openNetwork tags. Simply clobber over the xml file:

`$result | Out-File -Force C:\foo.xml`

EDIT: Okay, that file is drastically different than the one you provided the first time, but this solution will still work if you follow the structure of the xml. xml data types reference "nodes" with dotted address structure. The logic here provides a means of filtering through each node to collect only the relevant parts.